# Synth Look and Feel not doing anything?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the Synth look and feel and it is not doing anything to the look of the actual software. My file path is correct as I have checked that. Does anybody know why this is not working:

Java:

```
try {
    SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
    laf.load(new FileInputStream("src/look_and_feel.xml"), Truss.class);
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
} catch (Exception e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

XML:

```
<synth>
    <style id="default">
        <font name="Courier" size="14" />
    </style>
    <bind style="default" type="region" key="Button" />
</synth>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of loading the Look-And-Feel is:

```
SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();
laf.load(Truss.class.getResourceAsStream("laf.xml"), Truss.class);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
```

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Your problem seems to be the way of loading your xml-resource.

Therefore read about the difference of getting the streams [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308188/2427291)

Additionally take a closer look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Comment: I have tried that although Java throws this exception:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an InputStream,     StyleFactory and Class or URL

Comment: I have made the link work, although the actual XML simply does not do anything! I have even copied and pasted directly from tutorials just to test and nothing works!